# Python Dictionary Iteration Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

```
Favorite_Places = {"Jeff": ["Chicago","Berlin","Munchen"],
"Kai": ["New York", "Washington"],
"Sally": ["Texas", "Dublin"],
"Betty": "Bahrein"
}

for k,v in Favorite_Places.items():

    if len(str(v)) > 1:
        print(k + "'s " + "favourite places are")
    for i in v:
        if len(i) > 1:
            print(i)
        else:
            print(k + "'s " + "favourite places is " + v)
            break
```

```
Jeff's favourite places are
Chicago
Berlin
Munchen
Kai's favourite places are
New York
Washington
Sally's favourite places are
Texas
Dublin
Betty's favourite places are
Betty's favourite places is Bahrein
```

I get an output like this. How can I remove the part that says "Betty's favourite places are"?

Comment: Based on what logic? You've not said why Betty should be excluded. If it's just her name, why don't you test for that before you print it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `isinstance` to check if value is list

**Ex:**

```
for k,v in Favorite_Places.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        print(k + "'s " + "favourite places are")
        for i in v:
            print(i)
    else:
        print(k + "'s " + "favourite places is " + v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use isinstance to check if value is String

```
for k,v in Favorite_Places.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
      print(k + "'s " + "favourite places is " + v)   
    else:
      print(k + "'s " + "favourite places are")
      for i in v:
          print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to use lowercase for python variables names like Favourite_Places are usually used for classes. 
Secondly, you can definitely do what Rakesh suggested, but I would try to convert all values to a list, it's much easier to understand what's going on.
My example:

```
favorite_places = {"Jeff": ["Chicago","Berlin","Munchen"], "Kai": ["New York", "Washington"], "Sally": ["Texas", "Dublin"], "Betty": ["Bahrein"] }

for key, value in favorite_places.items():

    print(key + "'s " + "favourite places ", end='')

    if len(value) >= 2:
        print(f"are {', '.join(value)}.")
    else:
        print(f"is {value[0]}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to:

```
if len(v) > 1:
        print(k + "'s " + "favourite places are")
```